# Multiple css backgrounds with gif animation suddenly broken i chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, gif

We have been running a browser strategy game for about 5 years. Our animated water worked for a couple of years but is suddenly broken in chrome. Still works in other browsers. The bug showed up in chrome canary (developer version of chrome) a few months back, and now also in normal chrome.

Here is a example of how our css looks like:
    background:url(ver101/terrain/water/128patt.gif) -384px -320px, 
    url(ver101/terrain/water/wbase.png) -384px -320px; 
    width:64px; height:64px;

Here is what it looks like in the browser: http://www.warbarons.com/testwater.html

The first background layer have a animated gif where each frame only contain the pixels that are changed, the rest is transparent. The next background layer is a static image of water. The result is a optimized gif animation of water where we don't need to hold information that doesn't change in every frame of the gif.

The problem that we have now is that the second layer is not displayed. If I put a transparent static PNG image in the first layer the second layer is drawn, but not with the animated gif.

We have been running this game for a long time with no problem, and the interesting part now is that it worked in chrome until we cleared our cache (after getting complaints from our players). This would make it seem like we have changed something the broke it but it still works in firefox after clearing cache, and all our older versions of the game that we haven't touched are also broken now in chrome.
It seems to me that this is a bug introduced in chrome, but I'm probably wrong. Any suggestion to get this back working would be great for us and our players who are suffering from flashing disco water.